# Flutter: How do I get the serial number of the device?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, handheld

I'm using Flutter and the [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) package. I made sure to add this permission in the manifest, but it still doesn't work:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

**The code:**

```
final deviceInfoPlugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();
final deviceInfo = await deviceInfoPlugin.deviceInfo;
final serialNumber = deviceInfo.data['serialNumber']; //Returns "unknown"
```

Comment: The vendors are rightfully making it harder and harder to get unique IDs.  If you want to distinguish your app installations, store a UUID in local storage.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I just need it because we want to track data from our handhelds based on a unique ID of the handheld. And since our purchase receipts already show the serial number, using this number would make our data in accounting match the user data we log in the database.

Comment: I agree with the vendors on this.  (1) Privacy, (2) ease of replacement if I lost my phone or want to upgrade.  Your UUID stored in local storage will transfer to the new phone, but a device ID won't.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz fair enough